# Общая обработка событий "keyup" и "click" для разных элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Функция `keyup()` срабатывает, когда я ввожу текст в поле для поиска. Мне нужно, чтобы при клике по `id="add_text"` эта функция тоже сработала.

HTML:

```
<div id="add_text">Добавить</div>
```

JS:

```
$searchInput.keyup(function(e) { //данные которые нужно выполнить });
```

Comment: Можно ли выполнить такое действие через if else в js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно функцию, вызываемую при событиях `keyup` и `click`, предварительно объявить, после чего использовать её имя в обработчиках событий:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function handler() {
        console.log('Called');
    }
    var $searchInput = $('#search_input');
    $searchInput.on('keyup', handler);
    $('#add_text').on('click', handler);
});
```

```html
<input id="search_input" />
<div id="add_text">Добавить</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать выполнение обработчика события через функцию .triggerHandler()

```
  $($searchInput).triggerHandler('keyup');
```